# How to deal with many social widgets on the same page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, linkedin-api, google-plus

Theoretically, this question has been [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152971/many-share-buttons-for-social-networks-on-one-page). Though, I have technical question.

I use Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google +. I prefer the lazy loading approach. In this scenario content-specific buttons are loaded only when user navigates to the content.

However, how to achieve this? Facebook has [FB.XFBML.parse();](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/), which parses selected part of the content (when DOMElement argument is passed). What about the other social widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- LinkedIn [uses](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui) `IN.parse(domNode)`
- Twitter [uses](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/890) `twttr.widgets.load()`
- Google+ [uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7628992/357801) `gapi.plusone.go()`

Comment: That's awesome. It doesn't work exactly the same way I needed (e.g. it doesn't allow to define the DOM selector), though with a little sugar on the top it will do the magic.